# Non trivial zeros of Riemann zeta function

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

> **Question**  Define $f(z)=(s-1)\zeta(s)$ where $s=\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ and $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function. Prove that if $\rho$ denotes the non trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ then, $$\sum_{|\alpha|<1,f(\alpha)=0}\log \frac{1}{|\alpha|^2}=\sum_{\Re(\rho)>1/2} \log\left|\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}\right|$$
> I am reading [a paper by Balazard et al.](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Notes-sur-la-fonction%CE%B6de-Riemann%2C-2-Balazard-Saias/1e9f1a23efa0b569f4786944172d0f21b8863089) on the zeta function where both sums converge.

My try-
$\rho=\frac{1}{1+\alpha^2}$ then $\alpha^2=\frac{1-\rho}{\rho}$ so that $\alpha=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1-\rho}{\rho}}$
$$\sum_{|\alpha|<1,f(\alpha)=0}\log \frac{1}{|\alpha|^2}=\sum_{-\pi<\arg(\alpha)\leq \pi,|\alpha|<1,f(\alpha)=0}\log \frac{1}{|\alpha|^2}    $$
Since the sum on the right hand side is absolutely convergent so we can write the sum in any order.$$\sum_{|\alpha|<1,f(\alpha)=0}\log \frac{1}{|\alpha|^2}=\sum_{-\pi<\arg(\alpha)\leq 0}\log \frac{1}{|\alpha|^2}+  \sum_{0<\arg(\alpha)\leq \pi}\log \frac{1}{|\alpha|^2}     $$
$\rho=\frac{1}{1+\alpha^2}$ is injective on $-\pi<\arg(\alpha)\leq 0$ and also it is injective on $0<\arg(\alpha)\leq \pi$.
So using $\rho=\frac{1}{1+\alpha^2}$ we get,
$$\sum_{|\alpha|<1,f(\alpha)=0}\log \frac{1}{|\alpha|^2}=\sum_{-\pi/2<\arg(\rho)<\pi/2}\log\left|\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}\right|+ \sum_{-\pi/2<\arg(\rho)<\pi/2}\log\left|\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}\right|  $$

Comment: Why do all these sums converge?

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე Because they are part of Jensen's formula and Balazard Saias and Yor has proved that they converge

Comment: Why don't you add links to these?

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე Please see 
- https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Notes-sur-la-fonction%CE%B6de-Riemann%2C-2-Balazard-Saias/1e9f1a23efa0b569f4786944172d0f21b8863089

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე     Please see here for english free version --https://thosgood.com/translations/

Comment: Thank you, but it would be better to give this link at the appropriate place in the question - for example before the first display you could say that the right hand side of the equality absolutely converges according to them, and you ask whether the left hand side does too and gives the same value.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე Please assume that the sums converge or please look at the link. Please answer the question. It is a request

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე I have added the reference in the question itself. I apologise for any mistakes as I am new to this site

Comment: Thank you, this is better. Although it would be even better to explain that according to the paper you refer to the right hand side of your first display represents a well-defined value.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე It indeed represents a finite number. See this answer - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3953760/int-infty-infty-frac-log-zeta-frac12it-frac14t2-m?r=SearchResults

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე Please answer the question. I will happily give it a check mark.

Comment: One question please. In some of your remarks you say "it is a request". What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as the latest iteration of the persistent efforts of a repeat offender.

Answer (score 14):

Authors of the paper you linked actually define $f(z)$ differently. They have
$$
f(z)=\left(\frac{1}{1-z}-1\right)\zeta\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right),
$$
so your $f(z)$ is their $f(-z^2)$ and every $\alpha$ in their formula corresponds to $\pm i\alpha$ from yours, so the sum on the left should actually be $\frac12$ of what is in the question, so
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{-\pi/2<\arg(\rho)<\pi/2}\log\left|\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}\right|+ \sum_{-\pi/2<\arg(\rho)<\pi/2}\log\left|\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}\right|\right)=\sum_{-\pi/2<\arg(\rho)<\pi/2}\log\left|\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}\right|
$$
and everything works just fine, no contradiction.

P.S. And yeah, unfortunately the Riemann hypothesis is still hard.

Edit for clarity: By "should actually be" I mean that to replicate the result of Balazard-Saias-Yor you should take another function. To elaborate further, let
$$
f_S(z)=\left(\frac{1}{z^2+1}-1\right)\zeta\left(\frac{1}{z^2+1}\right)
$$
be the Shyla's function,
$$
f_{BSY}(z)=\left(\frac{1}{1-z}-1\right)\zeta\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
$$
be the Balazard-Saias-Yor function and three constants $A,B,C$ be
$$
A=\sum_{\substack{|\alpha|<1\\ f_S(\alpha)=0}}\log\frac{1}{|\alpha|^2},
$$

$$
B=\sum_{\substack{|\alpha|<1\\ f_{BSY}(\alpha)=0}}\log\frac{1}{|\alpha|}
$$
and
$$
C=\sum_{-\pi/2<\mathrm{arg}\,\rho<\pi/2}\log\left|\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}\right|.
$$
Then the proof of Shyla shows that $A=2C$, which is clearly equivalent to Balazard-Saias-Yor paper's $B=C$ (both are true), while the formula in question is $A=C$, which is equivalent to $C=0$, which is easily seen to be the same as the Riemann hypothesis, becuase then the sum in the definition should necessarily be empty.

Comment: are you saying that $$\sum_{|\alpha|<1,f(\alpha)=0}\log \frac{1}{|\alpha|^2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{-\pi/2<\arg(\rho)<\pi/2}\log\left|\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}\right|+ \sum_{-\pi/2<\arg(\rho)<\pi/2}\log\left|\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}\right| \right) $$?

Comment: @Shyla No, your final formula is correct, it's equivalent to what is stated in the article you linked. However, the formula in the Question is not true. I mean, it's truth is actually equivalent to RH. Also it is not the formula from the article.

Comment: How is the sum in the left , $\sum_{|\alpha|<1,f(\alpha)=0} \log\frac{1}{|\alpha|^2}$ equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ times the sum $\sum_{-\pi/2<\arg(\rho)<\pi/2}\log\left|\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}\right|  +   \sum_{-\pi/2<\arg(\rho)<\pi/2}\log\left|\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}\right| $

Comment: Which formula is correct?

Comment: The truth of which formula is equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis?

Comment: Clarifying comment added. By "not true" above I mean "equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis, so is not contained in the linked paper and also not likely to be derived as easily as the formula from the paper"

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate on how we get $A=2C$?

Comment: The last formula in your question states that $A=C+C$. It is true and derivation is correct.

Comment: can you please give a counterexample that $A\neq C$? I think that $A=C$.

Comment: I already explained in the comment above what I mean by "not true". It is more like "not necessarily true, to our knowledge". I also think that the Riemann hypothesis is true, actually

Comment: Is it somewhere proved apart from Balazard et al. that $A=C$ is equivalent to RH?

Comment: It is esentially the same as Balazard-Saias-Yor criterion, so probably not.